# Renaming PHP files to something other than .php

Tags: php, mysql

This might seem like a very easy answer but I cant seem to wrap my head around it. How would I rename files? For instance if I wanted to rename index.php to "home" or something. How would I go about doing that?

Also, how would I rename user pages? Instead of example.com/profile.php?id=28, something like example.com/users/mrexample

Thanks a bunch guys!

Comment: What OS are you using?  Windows?  Linux?

Comment: You'll love CodeIgniter if you want to switch to MVC :), other than that there is htaccess solutions.

Comment: That's called *Pretty URLs*, search for them on SO or Google.

Comment: Im using linux. @david how would I get that set up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep the existing file structure on the server and present pretty URLs as you described, this is called URL Routing. If you're using Apache then `mod_rewrite` is the way to go. Lighttpd also supports rewrites. I believe a commercial rewrite plugin is available for IIS.

You can either create a set of rewrite rules that match URL queries and pass them on to the relevant PHP file, or have a single rewrite rule that forwards all requests to a single PHP script which calls the appropriate function/script/template/include.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

You can call them whatever you like, so long as the web server understands that they need to be handled as PHP scripts. One common mechanism for doing this under HTTPd is [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Answer (score 1):

This will help you a lot and solve your problem

http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Answer (score 0):

Look into using a framework to help you with pretty urls; you don't want to use a different extension for your php files for this problem.

Try [Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/)